# JPanel components not going where I want them to

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, layout-manager

```
public class PLogin extends JPanel {

private JButton loginButton;
private JLabel usernameLabel;
private JTextField loginField;
private JLabel passwordLabel;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JScrollPane scroller;
private JTextArea status;

public PLogin()
{
    loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    add(usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username"));
    add(loginField = new JTextField(20));
    add(passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password "));
    add(passwordField = new JPasswordField(20));
    add(loginButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    status = new JTextArea(null, "Waiting", 5, 15);
    status.setEditable(false);
    scroller = new JScrollPane(status);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    add(scroller, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}
```

Here is my code for my Login GUI Pane.

For some reason, the scroller and login button go next to each other.

```
Username : UsernameField
Password: PasswordField
Login    Scroller
```

I'd rather have

```
Login
Scroller
```

I've tried with `BorderLayout.CENTER` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH` - any ideas?

Comment: I suggest your read a tutorial on using layout manager. This one on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) would be a start.

Comment: I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: 1st recommendation I'd offer is to not try and use `BorderLayout` constraints in a `FlowLayout` (the default layout for a `JPanel`). General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: You could always do the cheap fix and add a empty JLabel after the login component.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I will look into it.

Comment: Kyal that is a good idea actually, if I can't find a fix, I'll do that.

Comment: Tip: Add @KyalBond (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. And on that 'empty label' suggestion. 1) An empty label will have no size, so that is pointless. 2) The same effect would be better achieved b using an `EmptyBorder`, but.. 3) Putting random 'pad spaces' in a GUI to achieve a specific effect is nothing more than a hack. Instead learn how to use layouts properly. - Further information might be forthcoming after you post the MCVE/SSCCE & ASCII art. I (and most people worth listening to) won't devote much thought to this until those things are present.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson , I'm going to look at many layout managers and figure it out better, I'll look what MCVE is.